# Multiple views and models in a Django project

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django 1.11 application and I'd like to break my models and views into separate packages. (The models were moved into their own directory some time ago and have been working without issue.)

So, the application structure will become:

```
app
  models
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
  views
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
  ...
```

I've done the above using [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/02/how-to-split-views-into-multiple-files.html) as a reference, but when attempting to import models in the newly nested views (a la `from models.foo import Foo`), I'm met with an error which says, `ImportError: No module named models.foo`.

Do I need to specify this new path in settings.py? Do I need to change my import statement? Something else?

Comment: Shouldn't this be, `from app.models.foo import Foo`? Normally the `PYTHON_PATH` is one level above the apps.

Comment: Thanks, @WillemVanOnsem. That was the issue. Please add that as an answer and I will happily to accept it.